# How to replace request objects from a dict of items using python?

Tags: python

I have a dict and request body as below.

```
dict_items = {"country":["india","uk","usa","srilanka"],"city":["delhi","london","new york","colombo"]}

payload = {
    "country": country,
    "city": city
}
```

How can I replace each country and city in the payload and generate a new request for each value in the dict. I need to get four payloads with each country and city from the dictionary. Please help me with this.

I have tried the following but not helpful.

```
for key,val in dict_items.items():
    i += 1
    if key == "country":
       for i in range(val):
           req_json['name'] = val[i]
           break
      if i == len(val):
         break
```

but the above is not giving the expected request objects. I need each request object to get the values from the dictionaries for each country and city.

Comment: Please show what you are expecting this code to produce.

Comment: So do you need 16 payloads in total?

Comment: I am expecting the below output

[
    {'country': 'india', 'city': 'delhi'}, 
    {'country': 'uk', 'city': 'london'}, 
    {'country': 'usa', 'city': 'new york'}, 
    {'country': 'srilanka', 'city': 'colombo'}
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with simplify the problem and getting all countries and cities in separate variables:

```
countries = dict_items["country"]
cities = dict_items["city"]
```

Now there are multiple ways, the simplest:

```
payloads = [{"country": country, "city": city} for country, city in zip(countries, cities)]
```

Now you can iterate over them and send proper requests or whatever you need them for:

```
for payload in payloads:
    requests.get(some_url, json=payload)
```

Comment: but this is giving me the following payload

Comment: [{'country': 'india', 'city': 'delhi'}, {'country': 'uk', 'city': 'delhi'}, {'country': 'usa', 'city': 'delhi'}, {'country': 'srilanka', 'city': 'delhi'}, {'country': 'india', 'city': 'london'}, {'country': 'uk', 'city': 'london'}, {'country': 'usa', 'city': 'london'}, {'country': 'srilanka', 'city': 'london'}, {'country': 'india', 'city': 'new york'}, {'country': 'uk', 'city': 'new york'}, {'country': 'usa', 'city': 'new york'}, {'country': 'srilanka', 'city': 'new york'}, {'country': 'india', 'city': 'colombo'}, {'country': 'uk', 'city': 'colombo'}, {'country': 'usa', 'city': 'colombo'}

Comment: {'country': 'srilanka', 'city': 'colombo'}]

Comment: I need 4 payloads that return each country and city from the list but not each city repeated for all the countries and so on

Comment: I am expecting below output

[
    {'country': 'india', 'city': 'delhi'}, 
    {'country': 'uk', 'city': 'london'}, 
    {'country': 'usa', 'city': 'new york'}, 
    {'country': 'srilanka', 'city': 'colombo'}
]

Comment: edited an answer